# Computing probability involving two exponential RVs

Tags: probability

I have two independent exponential RVs $T_1$ and $T_2$ (with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$) and I wish to compute:

$$P(t-T_2\le T_1\le t-x)$$

My work:

\begin{align*}
P(t-T_2\le T_1\le t-x) &=P(T_2\ge x)\times P(t-t_2\le T_1\le t-x\mid T_2=t_2, T_2\ge x)\\
&=\exp(-\mu x)\times \int_{t_2=x}^\infty \int_{t-t_2}^{t-x}\lambda e^{-\lambda t_1} \mu e^{-\mu t_2}dt_1 dt_2\\
&=e^{-\lambda(t-x)-2\mu x}\frac{\lambda}{\mu-\lambda} (\text{for } \mu>\lambda)
\end{align*}

Is this correct?